# Angular reactive forms: sync multiple inputs with a single formControlName

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular11

I'm building a [reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) in Angular 11. It's split up across multiple divs, and the project owner wants a few repeated inputs in each of those divs so that a user can edit an input for some field A, and all of the divs' inputs for field A will show the updated value.

I like [corylan's approach](https://coryrylan.com/blog/syncing-multiple-reactive-form-inputs-in-angular):

```html
<input [formControl]="myCtrl" [value]="myCtrl.value" />
<input [formControl]="myCtrl" [value]="myCtrl.value" />
<input [formControl]="myCtrl" [value]="myCtrl.value" />
```

...but I want to achieve this with `formControlName` instead of `formControl` so that I can take advantage of `formGroup`s (and not have each form control be a member of my component object). However, lacking a reference to the the actual `myCtrl` would ruin the binding at `[value]`.

Is there a good strategy for me to specify the form control by name only *and* have all of these inputs use a single control? Or is there a different good way to sync inputs in Angular reactive forms when there are quite a few different sets to sync?

Comment: I you can try it with [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray)

Comment: @akkonrad kind of, but there are two problems: (1) unless I'm working with inputs that lend themselves to an array, the use of of FormArray would make the surrounding component brittle. (If I ever need to add or remove an element, the indicies for all subsequent elements needs to be changed. And if one of our html/css guys adds/removes an input, he's going to have no idea why everything broke, and (2) my ng app still wouldn't compile because my inputs exist before some of the controls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting value to the forms controls actual value.

```html
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <input placeholder="search" formControlName="search" [value]="searchForm.value.search" />
  <input placeholder="search" formControlName="search" [value]="searchForm.value.search" />
  <input placeholder="search" formControlName="search" [value]="searchForm.value.search" />
</form>
```

STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6gxf6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Good answer. I would add that you can also use `searchForm.value.search` for the value property.