# Sync two input fields with one FormControl

Tags: angular, typescript

If you have a component with 1 **FromControl**, connected to two input fields:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<input [formControl]="ctrl"><input [formControl]="ctrl">',
})
export class AppComponent {
    ctrl = new FormControl('x', { updateOn: 'change' });
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bqvmki?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I was surprised to notice that when I type in one, the other was not updated. Can someone explain to me why this is not happening. After a made the following template modification

```
<input [formControl]="ctrl" (input)="onChange($event)" />
<input [formControl]="ctrl" />
```

With

```
onChange(event) {
    this.ctrl.patchValue(e.target.value);
}
```

they were in sync!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular reactive forms: sync multiple inputs with a single formControlName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347952/angular-reactive-forms-sync-multiple-inputs-with-a-single-formcontrolname)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But that doesn't answerk my question. That post uses `[value]="myCtrl.value" ` to sync the inputs. It feels wrong to use `[value]="myCtrl.value"` in combination with `[formControl]="..."`

Answer (score 1):

I will try my best to explain this as clear as possible.
To shorten this answer, I have to make some assumptions, you should know about these. If you don't, kindly [read this article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1055/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms)

- Forms in angular works through ControlValueAccessor
- With normal input, it uses [DefaultValueAccessor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts)

The flow then goes like this:, please also read the comments in each function, those are my comments:

1. Every formControl needs to connect with its ControlValueAccessor. And angular does it for us via DI.
   This is [the line](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ae712ef6dddc8caadd7bf94b350b98969bff8f69/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_directive.ts#L121) we interested in:

   **setUpControl(this.form, this, this.callSetDisabledState);**
2. "setUpControl" set up 2 listeners:

- setUpViewChangePipeline: for view change (input change)
- setUpModelChangePipeline: for model change (class's property change)

And this is how setUpControl looks like

```
export function setUpControl(
    control: FormControl, dir: NgControl,
    callSetDisabledState: SetDisabledStateOption = setDisabledStateDefault): void {
  

  //This is where the default value set
  dir.valueAccessor!.writeValue(control.value);

  //The names is descriptive
  //This is for input -> control
  setUpViewChangePipeline(control, dir);
  //This is for control -> input
  setUpModelChangePipeline(control, dir);
}
```

This is [setUpViewChangePipeLine](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ae712ef6dddc8caadd7bf94b350b98969bff8f69/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L240)

```
function setUpViewChangePipeline(control: FormControl, dir: NgControl): void {

  //this basically means when we enter some value into the form 
  //-> it will trigger updateControl function
  dir.valueAccessor!.registerOnChange((newValue: any) => {
    updateControl(control, dir);
  });
}
```

This is [setUpModelChangePipeline](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ae712ef6dddc8caadd7bf94b350b98969bff8f69/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L266)

```
function setUpModelChangePipeline(control: FormControl, dir: NgControl): void {

  //viewToModelUpdate will emit ngModelChange event 
  const onChange = (newValue?: any, emitModelEvent?: boolean) => {
    // control -> view
    dir.valueAccessor!.writeValue(newValue);

    // control -> ngModel
    if (emitModelEvent) dir.viewToModelUpdate(newValue);
  };
  control.registerOnChange(onChange);
}
```

3. In "setUpViewChangePipeline" trigger control.update but with the option `emitModelToViewChange` set to false, which is the equivalent to telling angular don't update the value of model to view.
   => Meaning when you enter some value, it only update the model, and it stops there. No modelToView => that's why the other input won't get updated.

This is the [updateControl](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ae712ef6dddc8caadd7bf94b350b98969bff8f69/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L259)

```
//The think we care about is the setValue function
//The second option: emitModelToViewChange is set to false
function updateControl(control: FormControl, dir: NgControl): void {
  if (control._pendingDirty) control.markAsDirty();
  control.setValue(control._pendingValue, {emitModelToViewChange: false});
  dir.viewToModelUpdate(control._pendingValue);
  control._pendingChange = false;
}
```

4. "setUpModelChangePipeline" registers a callback into the control. Whenever the control change, trigger this callback.

- The callback does 2 things: update the view and also update the model. This is why when you update the model programmatically, 2 inputs update with same value.
- The way you update model programmatically is via `patchValue` or `setValue`. Let's check them below

This is [patchValue and setValue](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/208f52209bfc2425c90752e795704c08435d4d77/packages/forms/src/model/form_control.ts#L453)

```
//if emitModelToViewChange === false => no trigger onChange function
//if it is true, loop thru registered onChangeFns and trigger one by one
override setValue(value: TValue, options: {
        onlySelf?: boolean,
        emitEvent?: boolean,
        emitModelToViewChange?: boolean,
        emitViewToModelChange?: boolean
      } = {}): void {
        (this as {value: TValue}).value = this._pendingValue = value;
        if (this._onChange.length && options.emitModelToViewChange !== false) {
          this._onChange.forEach(
              (changeFn) => changeFn(this.value, options.emitViewToModelChange !== false));
        }
        this.updateValueAndValidity(options);
      }

      override patchValue(value: TValue, options: {
        onlySelf?: boolean,
        emitEvent?: boolean,
        emitModelToViewChange?: boolean,
        emitViewToModelChange?: boolean
      } = {}): void {
        this.setValue(value, options);
      }
```

Comment: Jimmy, I feel it's more easy: "you can not use two inputs with the same formControl because one has not take account when you change the another one"

Comment: Hi Eliseo, I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. The post is about "why", he didn't ask for the solution. Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

you can not use two inputs with the same formControl because one has not take account when you change the another one (except is your inputs are radio buttons with the same name)

But you can use in .html [formControl] and [ngModel] in the way

```
<input [formControl]="ctrl" />
<input [ngModel]="ctrl.value" 
       (ngModelChange)="ctrl.setValue($event)"
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
/>
```

See that each time you change the second input, change the control using setValue and get the value from ctrl.value

Answer (score -1):

If you update the value in the first input -> it updates in the second one.

The first one is not updated if you change the second one because you are not calling a function on the input (the second one) and the value of ctrl is not updated.

Here is the solution:

```
<input [formControl]="ctrl" (input)="onChange($event)" />
<input [formControl]="ctrl" (input)="onChange($event)" />
```

Comment: The last piece of code by OP is only a theoretical fix - not the described problem.